# Convert a series of given data frames into a single list by using an R function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I would like to convert a series of given data frames into a list by using an R function.

For instance, I have 3 dataframes:

```
A <- data.frame(m = c(121, 122, 121, 122, 125, 126), r = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2),q1 = c(124, 126, 126, 122, 125, 126), q2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2))
B = data.frame(m = c(121, 121, 122, 125), r = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2), q3 = c(126, 126, 125, 126), q4 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2))
C = data.frame(m = c(121, 122), r = c(0.1, 0.4), q5 = c(126, 126), q6 = c(0.1, 0.3))
```

I would like to write a function:

```
function(x){
result <- list(x)
return(result)
```

}

if my input is `A`, I want to get the result `list(A)`; and if my input is `A, B, C`, I would like to get `list(A, B, C)`

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why not just use the `list()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `...` optional arguments

```
list_conversion <- function(x, ...) {
   list(x, ...)
}

list_conversion(A)
#[[1]]
#    m   r  q1  q2
#1 121 0.1 124 0.1
#2 122 0.2 126 0.2
#3 121 0.3 126 0.3
#4 122 0.4 122 0.4
#5 125 0.1 125 0.1
#6 126 0.2 126 0.2

list_conversion(A, B)
#[[1]]
#    m   r  q1  q2
#1 121 0.1 124 0.1
#2 122 0.2 126 0.2
#3 121 0.3 126 0.3
#4 122 0.4 122 0.4
#5 125 0.1 125 0.1
#6 126 0.2 126 0.2

#[[2]]
#    m   r  q3  q4
#1 121 0.1 126 0.1
#2 121 0.3 126 0.3
#3 122 0.4 125 0.4
#4 125 0.2 126 0.2
```

it would work in any number of arguments

```
list_conversion(A, B, C)
#[[1]]
#    m   r  q1  q2
#1 121 0.1 124 0.1
#2 122 0.2 126 0.2
#3 121 0.3 126 0.3
#4 122 0.4 122 0.4
#5 125 0.1 125 0.1
#6 126 0.2 126 0.2

#[[2]]
#    m   r  q3  q4
#1 121 0.1 126 0.1
#2 121 0.3 126 0.3
#3 122 0.4 125 0.4
#4 125 0.2 126 0.2

#[[3]]
#    m   r  q5  q6
#1 121 0.1 126 0.1
#2 122 0.4 126 0.3
```